# c++ user defined random number generator

Tags: c++

I am having some trouble generating 10 random numbers between a user defined range.

I have this so far:

```
int minimum, maximum, randNum;

cout << "Hello, please insert the smallest number for your range of random numbers" << endl;
cin >> minimum;
cout << "Please insert your largest number for your range of random numbers" << endl;
cin >> maximum;

srand (time(NULL));
randNum = rand()%(maximum-minimum)+minimum;
```

Not really sure where to go from here.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: [std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    int minimum, maximum;
    std::cin >> minimum >> maximum;

    // Create a random number generator
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    // We want random numbers within [minimum, maximum]
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(minimum, maximum);

    // Print 10 random numbers    
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: bit too advanced for me.  not that far in my learning but thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should just make a simple loop around your random number generating code, pushing each value into a vector.  Have the condition of the loop be like so:

```
for(int i =0; i < 10; ++i)
```

Overall you should have something like this:

```
srand(time(NULL));
vector<int> vec;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    vec.push_back(rand() % max + min);
}
```

All 10 numbers will be in your vector.  Or some method along those lines.